# StackLayout transparent color

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I need some help, I would like to set a button at a fixed location on the bottom of UI, how to do this using Xamarin.Forms? Also i want to set transparent color on StackLayout but no luck.

```
<ScrollView>
    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="fds"/>
        <Label Text="fds"/>
        <Label Text="fds"/>
        <Label Text="fds"/>
        <Label Text="fds"/>
        <Label Text="fds"/>
        <Label Text="fds"/>
        <Label Text="fds"/>
        <Label Text="fds"/>
        <Label Text="fds"/>
        <Label Text="fds"/>
        <Label Text="fds"/>
        <Label Text="fds"/>
        <Label Text="fds"/>
        <Label Text="fds"/>
        <Label Text="fds"/>
        <Label Text="fds"/>
        <Label Text="fds"/>
        <Label Text="fds"/>
        <Label Text="fds"/>
        <Label Text="fds"/>
        <Label Text="fds"/>
        <Label Text="fds"/>
        <Label Text="fds"/>
        <Label Text="fds"/>
        <Label Text="fds"/>
        <Label Text="fds"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
<StackLayout BackgroundColor="LightBlue" Opacity="0.3" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="End">
    <Button CornerRadius="30" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"  VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
</StackLayout>
```

In previewer 
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1zbS.png) 
It is transparent.
On phone 
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CgLW3.png)

Comment: Your two images appear identical to me.  If you want your StackLayout to be transparent, why is the color set to "LightBlue"?

Comment: @Jason No see first again text is appear behind StackLayout

Comment: The first image seems to have an unnatural behaviour. @Jason Is it normal for the `Opacity` property in the bottom `StackLayout` to make the labels in the `ScrollView` visible ?

Comment: What is your requirement? puting a button at bottom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to place a button bottom of your UI, use grid

```
    <Grid Margin="10" >

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <ScrollView>
            <StackLayout>
                <Label Text="fds"/>
                <Label Text="fds"/>
                <Label Text="fds"/>
                <Label Text="fds"/>
                <Label Text="fds"/>
                <Label Text="fds"/>
                <Label Text="fds"/>
                <Label Text="fds"/>
                <Label Text="fds"/>
                <Label Text="fds"/>
                <Label Text="fds"/>
                <Label Text="fds"/>
                <Label Text="fds"/>
                <Label Text="fds"/>
                <Label Text="fds"/>
                <Label Text="fds"/>
                <Label Text="fds"/>
                <Label Text="fds"/>
                <Label Text="fds"/>
                <Label Text="fds"/>
                <Label Text="fds"/>
                <Label Text="fds"/>
                <Label Text="fds"/>
                <Label Text="fds"/>
                <Label Text="fds"/>
                <Label Text="fds"/>
                <Label Text="fds"/>
                <Label Text="fds"/>
                <Label Text="fds"/>
                <Label Text="fds"/>
                <Label Text="fds"/>
                <Label Text="fds"/>
                <Label Text="fds"/>
                <Label Text="fds"/>
                <Label Text="fds"/>
                <Label Text="fds"/>
                <Label Text="fds"/>
                <Label Text="fds"/>
                <Label Text="fds"/>
                <Label Text="fds"/>
                <Label Text="fds"/>
                <Label Text="fds"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>


    </StackLayout>

        <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" BackgroundColor="Transparent" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="End">
        <Button CornerRadius="25" VerticalOptions="End" Margin="5,0,5,0" Text="Your Button" FontSize="Small" TextColor="White" BackgroundColor="#40db7093"></Button>
        </StackLayout>

    </Grid>
```

You can place whatever controls inside the first stacklayout.

Comment: Yes but what about scrollview?

Comment: Yes you can add scrollview outer the grid

Comment: Or you can use a listview inside the first stacklayout ie; the Grid.Row 0

Comment: I dont understand..What example yoy need?

Comment: I dont know why i lost transparent color but when i add scrollview  i got white background on button

Comment: see image without scroll view i got transparent color

Comment: Give me some time

Comment: I don't keep that

Comment: Can you elborate your problem? You want a button at the bottom. Then some labels to fill entire screen without scrollview. Right?

Comment: I want [image](https://imgur.com/a/o7E07jE) button like this (stay transparent) and when i scrolling labels the button should keep transparent color